# Fetching empty column with where clause MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a table where I want to show the data where one column is empty.

I tried everything but nothing seems to work

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tblleaves where empid=:eid and EndKm is NULL order by PostingDate desc";
```

In other words, I want to fetch data where `endkm` column is empty or has spaces only.

If I remove `EndKm` is NULL everything works fine for me.

Comment: Empty and null are completely different. If you want to get things that are e.g. empty string, `WHERE EndKm = ''` may work.

Comment: @Jonnix thanks for your help. I really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT * from tblleaves where empid=:eid and (EndKm IS NULL or TRIM(EndKm) = '') order by PostingDate desc`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping